Im using XTB's api xApi. I need help using 'offset' and 'sl' when making a trade

`Hi Im trying to automate trades in xAPI. sell trades work fine using :


This is to open a sell trade ie  cmd = 1 type = 0.
offset = 50 sl = 50 I get an open trade with a 5 pip trailing stop.  This is what I expected.


When trying to make a buy trade is cmd = 0 type = 0 using:
offset = -50 sl = -50 a buy trade opens without a stop or trailing stop.
offset = 50 sl = 50 ERROR invalid sl/tp value.
offset = 1 sl = -50 ERROR invalid trailing stop.
offset = 0 sl = -50 a buy trade opens without a stop or trailing stop.
offset = -1 sl = -50 a buy trade opens without a stop or trailing stop.
offset = -10 sl = -50 a buy trade opens without a stop or trailing stop.


From these attempts it appears to me that sl needs to be negative for the buy trade ie stop loss is below the trade price.
Im fairly sure the problem is with offset but cant make head nor tail of it.


I was expecting the first result attempt to work.`

  def open_account():   
        '''
            opens an instanece to the API 
    '''
    #   print('open api')
    global open_ctr
    #open_ctr += 1
    host = 'xapia.x-station.eu' 
    ##this is the address for the demo account##'xapia.x-    station.eu' real account is         'xapi.xtb.com
    port = 5124         ##demo acc 5124  real 5112 
    USERID =  #   Account number 
    PASSWORD = # my password 
    
    host = socket.getaddrinfo(host, port)[0][4][0]
    global S
    global END
    
    context=ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
    context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
    context.check_hostname = False 
    context.load_default_certs()
    
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    S = context.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname=host)
    S.connect(('xapia.x-station.eu',5124))
    S.settimeout(5)

    parameters = {
        "command" : "login",
        "arguments" : {
            "userId": USERID,
            "password": PASSWORD
        }
    }
    packet = json.dumps(parameters, indent=4)
    S.send(packet.encode("UTF-8"))

    END = b'\n\n'
    response=b''
    while True:
        try:
            response += S.recv(8192)
        except: 
            print('67 login fail')
            open_account
        if END in response:
            pass
            open_ctr+=1 
    
            break

    def Close_account():
    '''
        Closes the open Instance 
    '''
    #   print('98               close api')
    global open_ctr
    #   open_ctr -= 1       
    parameters = {
        "command" : "logout"
    }
    packet = json.dumps(parameters, indent=4)
    try:
        S.send(packet.encode("UTF-8"))
    
        response = S.recv(8192)
        open_ctr-=1
    except:
        #print('Close account Failed ')
        Close_account()



    def open_a_trade(symbol, price , volume , cmd, sl, offset,  tp=0):
        '''
            opens the trade 
        '''

    
    end_date=get_server_time()
    order_result.iloc[0:0]
    order_result.loc[1,'datetime']=end_date
    order_result['symbol']=symbol
    order_result['cmd']=cmd
    order_result['offset']=offset
    order_result['sl']=sl
    order_result['tp']=tp
    order_result['volume']=volume
    order_result['price']=price

    open_account()
            

    parameters={
        "command": "tradeTransaction",
        "arguments": {
            "tradeTransInfo": {
                "cmd": cmd,
                "customComment": '',
                "expiration": 0,
                "offset": offset,
                "order": 0,
                "price": price,
                "sl": sl,
                "symbol": symbol,
                "type": 0,
                "volume": volume
                }
            }
                }
    packet = json.dumps(parameters, indent=4)
    S.send(packet.encode("UTF-8"))
    response_open_trade = S.recv(328192)
    ## open trade was timing out , changed open response time in open_account to 5s from 3.5s
    
    order_number_response=json.loads(response_open_trade)

    if order_number_response['status']==False:
        order_result['order_number_response']=order_number_response['status']
        print('427 order result')
        print(order_result)
        order_result.to_csv('order_result.csv', mode='a', index=False, header=False)
        
    else:   
        order_result['order_number_response']=order_number_response['returnData']['order']
    
        print('427 order result')
        print(order_result)
        order_result.to_csv('order_result.csv', mode='a', index=False, header=False)
    #       print('427 open worked')
    Close_account()


    # set values for the trade 

    symbol='GBPUSD'
    price=.61801
    volume=.2
    cmd=0
    offset=0
    sl=-50
    tp=0
    print('943 ' , sl)
    open_a_trade(symbol, price , volume , cmd, sl, offset, tp)


Does anyone know of any resources that are available that explain the xapi in better detail than the xApi playground ?
Ive tried xtb customer support they dont give any support for the API.


Sorry I don't know python, but why is your SL negative?
This is how I modify a trade to use a trailing stop
{
    "command": "tradeTransaction",
    "arguments": {
        "tradeTransInfo": {
            "cmd": 1,
            "order": xxx,
            "symbol": "GBPUSD",
            "type": 3,
            "volume": 0.2,
            "price": 1.29954,
            "sl": 1.29707,
            "offset": 15
        }
    }
}

